# How to save bank account to accept payouts from Paypal in react/node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal, payment

I am creating an app where user can sell/buy photos. All the money goes to one paypal account and earnings needs to be redistributed (payouts) every 1st of the month. The problem is there needs to be a form on the frontend where each user can enter his payout account. One option is to enter paypal account and it s good. THe problem is i dont know how to enter the other payout account option (bank account). I did not manage to find some stripe like ui elemets for saving bank account that does validation and sends all necessary ids and tokens for me that i can store on the backend. Is there some solution to this problem and what is the proper approach both on the frontend and the backend?

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal processing (including its Payouts service), you send funds to an email address or PayPal account and the owner of that email/PayPal account can in turn withdraw the funds to any bank in their PayPal account. You do not send to a bank account directly.

For sending money directly to bank accounts, you'll need a different solution than PayPal payouts -- for instance enterprises use something like [Hyperwallet payouts](https://www.hyperwallet.com/) (but that service may be beyond you)